# How to get values from Textbox within AJAX Tabcointainer Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a tabcontainer with 3 panels and each one has a a few textboxes and a submit button. I want to store the values of textboxes in a variable on button click. I am getting null value exception at fname = txt.text;

Source:

```
       <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"   runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>

        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
            style="margin-right: 38px"  Height="138px"  Width="402px">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">

              <ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><table><tr><td>First Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" /></td></tr><tr><td>Address:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" /></td></tr><tr><td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                                        onclick="Button1_Click1" /></td></tr></table></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>

</asp:TabPanel>

            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                    Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />


</ContentTemplate>

</asp:TabPanel>
            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <table>
               <tr> <td>User Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" /></td></tr>
               <tr> <td>Password:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" /></td></tr>

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>

 C# Code:



protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fname = "";
    string address = "";
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    TextBox txt = null;
    TextBox txt1 = null;


    txt = (TextBox)TabContainer1.Parent.FindControl("txtName");
    txt1 = (TextBox)TabContainer1.Parent.FindControl("txtAddress");
    fname = txt.Text;
    address = txt1.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string q = "insert into tabtable (firstname,address) values('" + txt + "','" + txt1 + "')";
    dboperation dbo = new dboperation();
    dt = dbo.insert(q);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reference this control directly since neither `TabContainer` nor `TabPanel` implements `INamingContainer`. Hence the `TextBox` is on top of the page:

so instead of

```
txt = (TextBox)TabContainer1.Parent.FindControl("txtName");
fname = txt.Text;
```

just

```
fname = this.txtName.Text;
```

Comment: Damn! I cant believe i spent 3 hours on something as stupid as that. Thanks !! :)

Comment: btw can you explain why do i have to use 'this' ?

Comment: @user1856304: You don't _have to_ use `this`. It should just underline my words, that it's on top of the page and not in a different NamingContainer.